# Use of sum function to get a value in sparkR

Tags: sparkr

I have a DataFrame 'data' in sparkR which contains ID= 1,2,.. and amount= 232, 303, 444, 10, ...
I want to check if the sum of amount is greater than 5000.

```
sum(data$amount ) > 5000
```

Now sparkR should return TRUE if its TRUE and FALSE otherwise but all I get is this message

```
Column (SUM(amount)>5000)
```

How can I check if it's true?

Comment: it seems like this should be possible in SparkR without having to collect to dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might not be the best possible solution, but it works. You did create a column of 1 item, but I did not find a way to get the result stored in that item, therefor I applied a different approach:

```
df   <- data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4),amount=c(232, 303, 444, 10))
data <- createDataFrame(sqlContext,df)

data <- withColumn(data, "constant", data$ID * 0)

sumFrame <- agg(groupBy(data, data$constant), sumAmount = sum(data$amount))

localResult <- collect(sumFrame)
localResult$sumAmount > 5000
```

With this approach, I create a DataFrame of 1 row, but a DataFrame is collectable to obtain the result.

Comment: My problem is that it takes time to do the collect-function, specially when I need to do this many times. Can one do it without using the collect-function?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? It is not the collect function that takes time: due to lazy-evaluation, that's the first place where code is actually evaluated. And why do you want to run this code multiple times?

Comment: If I just run it 1 time it still takes a lot of time. Over 1 min.

Comment: Since collect is the only place where you're code will actually run, other approaches will take the same amount of time.